# How to avoid a compiler warning in scala about a for loop?

Tags: scala, compiler-warnings

Following code can cause scalac gives me a warning : `"Replace with columnName.indices more ..."`.

```
for( i <- 0 until columnName.length) {
    // do something here...
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to fix it and make it compile without the warning. Can anyone tell me why the compiler gives the warning ? I think the `colunmName.length` might return an NULL. But I have already judge the condition at first with NPE.

Comment: try storing the value of columnName.length into a variable first before using it inside the for loop.

Comment: @jtitusj , Yes, but the compiler don't you do like that. It hopes you do with  for (j <- columnName.indices)

Comment: Are you using IntelliJ? This looks like an IntelliJ thing rather than a scalac thing.

Comment: @SethTisue, yes, I use the latest IntelliJ IDEA ,version 15.x. Are you sure it is a intellij issue rather than a scalac thing ?

Comment: Yes. `scalac -Xlint` does not warn on your code. Besides, scalac will issue a warning if it suspects some code may actually be incorrect, but it doesn't issue purely stylistic warnings where the code is perfectly good, but could be improved. At least, I don't know of any exceptions to that. IntelliJ is more active about suggesting possible improvements.

Comment: @SethTisue I see. thanks, bro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting the same warning few days back, in new version of scala they have replaced

```
for( i<- 0 until columnName.length) {
// do something here...
 }
```

with a short-cut

```
 for( i <- columnName.indices) {
// do something here...
}
```

just go to the warning message and press `alt+enter` and it gets replaced with the new code.what `columnName.indices` is returning is a Range of indexes in the `columnName` collection you have, same what `0 until columnName.length` was returning and based on the returned index we can iterate the collection.

Comment: thanks. I see. At first, I fix the code like for( i<- 0 until columnName.indices), So all the wrong ..........